# Blogger Contempo theme : I want to remove the description of all posts. resize image like feature blog image in CONTEMPO THEME

Tags: blogger, blogs

I want to remove the description of all posts from all pages of the website. And resize images like feature blog image ( But Medium size ) in CONTEMPO THEME.
Checkout featured post and another post

[Featured Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4rAm.png)

Right now all posts display like this :

[Another post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Yvn.png)

Sample website - http://lazycoder7.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these changes. go to theme > edit HTML.

1. removing a description

   ```css
   .post-snippet.snippet-container { display : none; }
   ```
2. Resize posts image.

- Search ".post-body .snippet-thumbnail" and Remove all the attributes from the below class

  ```css
  .post-body .snippet-thumbnail {
  }
  ```
- Search ".post-body .snippet-thumbnail img" and Give attribute to the below class.

  ```css
  .post-body .snippet-thumbnail img {
      width: 100%;
  }
  ```
- Search "(max-width: 800px) 20vw, 128px" and replace that tag with the below tag

  ```html
  <b:include
      data='{image: data:post.featuredImage, imageSizes: [256, 512, 945, 1684], imageRatio: &quot;945:600&quot;, 
          sourceSizes: &quot;(min-width: 954px) 842px, (min-width: 801px) calc(100vw - 112px), 
          calc(100vw - 64px)&quot;, enhancedSourceset: data:highRes }'
      name='responsiveImage'/>
  ```